# How to Ask a Professor to be thesis referee

Tags: thesis, peer-review, etiquette, professorship

I finished my thesis writing and my supervisor ask me to send it to another professor who he want to referee my thesis, I don't know this professor either he don't know me, The problem my supervisor refuse to talk with him first, just to tell him that he want him as a thesis referee.

I don't know what to say to him in the email when I send him my thesis.
Could you help me, please?

Comment: can you clarify why your supervisor does not  want to talk to a prospective thesis evaluator?  It seems to me that communications with referees (for a paper or a thesis) should not be handled by parties directly involved but done at arms length by a third party, but maybe your traditions are different.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Hello Dr. Foo,
>
> My advisor, Dr. Bar, recommended that I should contact you to referee my thesis, "Underwater Basket Weaving." I was wondering if I could meet with you to provide you the thesis and answer any questions you may about it beforehand. Please let me know if you'd be interested and, if you are, the best time and location for me to meet you. Thank you for your time.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> Spongebob

Be polite, be clear, be accommodating. Your professor is unlikely to introduce you two because he probably doesn't want to appear as if he's using the potential referee as a resource rather than as a colleague. Furthermore, interacting with people you don't know through e-mail and real life is commonplace in academia, so it stands to reason your supervisor would want you to try it out.

Comment: he is in another city far from me so a meeting is impossible, here's what I want to send: My name is .., I m a student 

At the recommendation of my supervisor, Professor ..., I am writing to humbly request your service and expertise to serve as an ``External thesis referee’’  

I attach below my thesis report.

I am grateful for your time and consideration and I have very much hope that you will be able to fulfill my request.

Yours sincerely,

Comment: Mention that your supervisor recommended that you should contact him/her to referee your theses.

Comment: Yes, cite your supervisor's recommendation as the reason.

Comment: ok I will cite the reason, thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the suggestion provided by "Compass", one idea might be to also motivate why his professional accomplishments make him suitable as a referee for your particular thesis. For instance: "Given your experience with A, B and C... ", "I believe that your knowledge about [super specific topic D] makes you the most suited ... of my thesis regarding E"